# Jsf 2.1 does not render composite component default command button label as expected. What's wrong?

Tags: jsf-2

That's a strange thing. If i write this component as is second command button has no label.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="bean" required="true"
        type="com.devoteam.faces.custom.MultiSelect" />
    <composite:attribute name="selezionaTutti" default="Seleziona Tutti"
        type="java.lang.String" />
    <composite:attribute name="deselezionaTutti" default="Deseleziona Tutti"
        type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:selectManyListbox value="#{cc.attrs.bean.listaSelezionati}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.bean.lista}" />
    </h:selectManyListbox>
    <h:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.bean.selezionaTutti}"
        value="#{cc.attrs.selezionaTutti}" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.bean.deselezionaTutti}"
        value="#{cc.attrs.deselezionaTutti}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

But if i move third interface attribute in first position, label comes out.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="deselezionaTutti" default="Deseleziona Tutti"
        type="java.lang.String" />
    <composite:attribute name="bean" required="true"
        type="com.devoteam.faces.custom.MultiSelect" />
    <composite:attribute name="selezionaTutti" default="Seleziona Tutti"
        type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>
```

I'm using mojarra 2.1.7 with tomcat 7.0.26. Maybe a mojarra bug?